# Unable to choose Ubuntu 13.10 during startup

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside an existing installation of Windows 7. Problem is, I am unable to choose between operating systems and Windows loads up by default! How can I fix this from within Windows since I can not access Ubuntu? I know this involves fixing the grub but I am unaware how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something went wrong with grub ... you can boot from a live distro and reinstall grub ([here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) a tutorial) or you can also get something like "supergrub", choose Ubuntu in OS list and boot Ubuntu, do a grub update and then reboot from your HDU.

Cheers,

Silvia